# Consuming events from multiple Azure Event Hubs in one Python program

Tags: python, azure, python-asyncio, azure-eventhub

I have two event hubs, each with its own consumer group. I would like to receive events from each of them at the same time but I don't see anything related to this in the [GitHub samples](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-python/tree/main/sdk/eventhub/azure-eventhub/samples).

More specifically, I would like to take advantage of `asyncio` for reading from the two topics concurrently but I'm new to asynchronous programming and I can't figure it out. I tried something like this but it never moves on to reading with `client2`:

```
async with client1:
    async with client2:
        await client1.receive_batch(...)
        await client2.receive_batch(...)
```

I also tried separating the `async with` statements and even tried adding `await asyncio.sleep(1)` in the `on_event_batch` function, just to make sure that control is given back to the event loop.

At this point I'm not sure whether what I want to do simply cannot be achieved with `asyncio` or I just don't know how to use it.

Any help will be appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

`receive_batch` is designed to be a blocking call which keeps pumping events from the event hub infinitely.

To facilitate `asyncio` for coroutine tasks execution concurrently, you could use `asyncio.create_task` to execute `receive_batch`.

Example code:

```py
async with client1, client2:
    future1 = asyncio.create_task(client1.receive_batch(...))
    future2 = asyncio.create_task(client2.receive_batch(...))
    results = await asyncio.gather(future1, future2)  # program will be blocking here waiting for two coroutines to finish
```

For more advanced usage of asyncio module, I would recommend you to take a look at the official Python docs for [Coroutines and Tasks](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html#coroutines-and-tasks).

Please let me know if there's any more I could help on.

Comment: Thanks Adam, it seems to be the right direction but unfortunately it's still not working. For each of the two clients, I successfully receive a batch and then I get this error:

`An error occurred while receiving. The exception is TypeError("object NoneType can't be used in 'await' expression").`

The whole thing then repeats itself: another batch is successfully received, another error comes along, and so on.

Any idea on how to fix it?